# cldr persian date in devextreme dxdatebox

Tags: javascript, globalization, devextreme, cldr

i am using dxdatebox in devextreme . after asking i finally implemented german calender in dxdatebox. now i want hav a persian calender and i have already try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DevExtreme Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/dx.common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/dx.light.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/cldr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/cldr/event.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/cldr/supplemental.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/globalize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/globalize/message.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/globalize/number.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/globalize/currency.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/globalize/date.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/dx.all.js"></script>

    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/localization/dx.all.de.js"></script>*@

</head>

<body>
    <div id="btnContainer"></div>
    <div id="dateContainer"></div>
    <script>

        $.when(
              $.getJSON("../cldr/main/fa/ca-persian.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/main/fa/numbers.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/main/fa/currencies.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/supplemental/weekData.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/supplemental/currencyData.json"),
              $.getJSON("../cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json")
            ).then(function () {
                return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
                    return result[0];
                });
            }).then(
                Globalize.load
            ).then(function () {

                Globalize.locale('fa');
                $('#dateContainer').dxDateBox({
                    value: new Date(),   
                });
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

but in console i got this error :`Unsupported {"feature":"Julian day pattern`g`"}.`

how can i convert gregorian calender to julian calender?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

no idea about your framework, but more generally

With this: https://github.com/kbwood/calendars
you can do like:

```
var d = $.calendars.newDate(1385, 6, 2, 'persian', 'fa');
console.log("Persian date: "+d.toLocaleString());
var e = d.toJSDate();
console.log(e);
```

Comment: its not working 'cause still i have the same error .

Comment: for details have a look at: http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html#convert

Comment: i am using globlize.js and cldr.js with thier dependencies. in globlize folder i have a js file name date,js.when i use cldr-persian with date.js i got the error above.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use globalize.js, Since its not supporting fa-IR locale.
You have to switch to INTL method:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/Localization/#Localize_Dates_Numbers_and_Currencies/Using_Intl